Optimizing query to filter many-to-many relationship on row-count
My model:
class RecipeTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None, db_index=True)
    recipes = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    language_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=[(lang[0], lang[1]) for lang in settings.LANGUAGES],
        default='en',
        db_index=True  # Index added here
    )
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None, db_index=True)  # Index added here
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=True, db_index=True)  # Index added here

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.tag)
        super(NewRecipeTag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        tag = self.tag if self.tag else "Tag"
        return f"{tag} - Visible - {self.is_visible}"

I need to filter all RecipeTag that have more then 2 recipes assigned to them, that I am currently doing like that
tags = NewRecipeTag.objects.filter(language_code=meta['language'],
    is_visible=True).annotate(num_recipes=Count('recipes')).filter(num_recipes__gte=2)

Then I paginate results like that to display:
paginator = Paginator(recipe_tags, 60)
page = paginator.page(page_number)
recipe_tags = page.object_list

The query takes around 20 seconds. Without annotate it happens almost instantly. I have 4391166 rows and hope to find a faster solution to display paginated tags filtered by recipe-count.

UPDATE
Actual model name is NewRecipeTag, but never mind.
Here is Recipe Model:
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author', default=None)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="dish_category", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="category_level", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    time = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="time", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipes')
    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=[('en', 'en'), ('uk', 'uk')],
        default='uk'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    image = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    filed_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default=None, upload_to="recipes_photos/")
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    sitemap_loc_pk = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=True)
    kitchen = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="kitchen", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    cook_methods = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="cook_methods", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    vegetarian = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    hot = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    dietary = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="category_dietary", blank=True, null=True,
                                  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)

    type_of_food = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="category_type_of_food", blank=True, null=True,
                                  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)

    season = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="category_season", blank=True, null=True,
                                  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)

    food_group = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="category_food_group", blank=True, null=True,
                               on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    new_tags_generated = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)

Query:
SELECT "recipe_newrecipetag"."id", "recipe_newrecipetag"."tag", "recipe_newrecipetag"."description", "recipe_newrecipetag"."seo_h1", "recipe_newrecipetag"."seo_title", "recipe_newrecipetag"."seo_description", "recipe_newrecipetag"."seo_text", "recipe_newrecipetag"."language_code", "recipe_newrecipetag"."slug", "recipe_newrecipetag"."is_visible", "recipe_newrecipetag"."sitemap_loc_pk", COUNT("recipe_newrecipetag_recipes"."recipe_id") AS "num_recipes"
FROM "recipe_newrecipetag" LEFT OUTER JOIN "recipe_newrecipetag_recipes" ON ("recipe_newrecipetag"."id" = "recipe_newrecipetag_recipes"."newrecipetag_id")
WHERE ("recipe_newrecipetag"."is_visible" AND "recipe_newrecipetag"."language_code" = uk)
GROUP BY "recipe_newrecipetag"."id"
HAVING COUNT("recipe_newrecipetag_recipes"."recipe_id") >= 2
ORDER BY "recipe_newrecipetag"."tag" ASC

EXPLAIN output:
Sort  (cost=3706458.92..3710089.69 rows=1452305 width=1555)
  Sort Key: recipe_newrecipetag.tag
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4576.12..609237.64 rows=1452305 width=1555)
        Group Key: recipe_newrecipetag.id
        Filter: (count(recipe_newrecipetag_recipes.recipe_id) >= 2)
        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=4576.12..525178.10 rows=5919621 width=1555)
              Merge Cond: (recipe_newrecipetag.id = recipe_newrecipetag_recipes.newrecipetag_id)
              ->  Index Scan using recipe_newrecipetag_pkey on recipe_newrecipetag  (cost=0.43..228510.04 rows=4356915 width=1547)
                    Filter: (is_visible AND ((language_code)::text = 'uk'::text))
              ->  Index Only Scan using recipe_newrecipetag_reci_newrecipetag_id_recipe_i_87147e82_uniq on recipe_newrecipetag_recipes  (cost=0.43..211664.16 rows=5966157 width=16)

Currently I am thinking about caching requests. But if there is a better option, I will go with that!

Could you please share the SQL, the DDL for all tables and indexes involved and the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this piece of SQL? All in plain text, as an update of your question.

Hey, thank you for a quick reply! I did it, let me know if i missed something

Thanks, but this is just the result from explain, not explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings). That's the one we need. A query plan is nice, but a plan is just a plan. It could be a good plan, it could be a bad plan. Without executing the plan you will never know. That why you need the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings). By the way, what PostgreSQL version do you use?

Please provide information as instructed here. Also, you say "more then 2 recipes assigned ", but your query shows COUNT(r.recipe_id) >= 2.
And "4391166 records"- but there are two tables. Please be precise.

Generally ...

Don't use a LEFT JOIN when existence of rows to the right is required anyway.
Aggregate first, join later.
count(*) is a bit faster when counting things that cannot be null. (Well, technically, the LEFT JOIN in your query could produce a null, but only one per recipe while >= 2 are needed to qualify.)

See:

Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0
Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query

Basically ...
If most rows pass is_visible AND language_code = uk:
SELECT t.id, t.tag, t.description, t.seo_h1, t.seo_title, t.seo_description, t.seo_text. t.language_code, t.slug, t.is_visible, t.sitemap_loc_pk
     , r.num_recipes
FROM   recipe_newrecipetag t
JOIN  (
   SELECT newrecipetag_id, count(*) AS num_recipes
   FROM   recipe_newrecipetag_recipes
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) > 1
   ) r ON r.newrecipetag_id = t.id
WHERE  t.is_visible
AND    t.language_code = uk
ORDER  BY t.tag;

Indexes won't help (much).
If few rows pass:
SELECT t.id, t.tag, t.description, t.seo_h1, t.seo_title, t.seo_description, t.seo_text. t.language_code, t.slug, t.is_visible, t.sitemap_loc_pk
     , r.num_recipes
FROM   recipe_newrecipetag t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL  (
   SELECT newrecipetag_id, count(*) AS num_recipes
   FROM   recipe_newrecipetag_recipes r
   WHERE  r.newrecipetag_id = t.id
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) > 1
   ) r 
WHERE  t.is_visible
AND    t.language_code = uk
ORDER  BY t.tag;

Indexing can help a lot. Best index setup depends on selectivity of the filter clauses, and the complete picture. Minimum setup:  indexes on recipe_newrecipetag(language_code) and recipe_newrecipetag_recipes(newrecipetag_id).
